# How big could a nuclear war be without causing an apocalypse?

Tags: environment, nuclear-war, nuclear-winter

It is widely known that an all out nuclear weapon with modern nuclear missiles would probably cause a nuclear winter, billions of deaths, and end life as we know it.

On the other hand, two small (by modern standards) A-bombs dropped on Japan in 1945, while causing hundreds of thousands of deaths in an instant, did not end life as we know it, and even Japan went on to recover and thrive as a world power within decades afterwards.

How large could the scale of a nuclear war that did not end life as we know it, and did not render more than a city sized area uninhabitable for more than a decade be?

Comment: I wonder if this question is answerable.. Do we have A-Bombs, H-Bombs, N-Bombs or a mix of these types.. Where would they be deployed first, what season, what winds are involved.. What do you classify as "big". Would it be half of the 2022 arsenal, and how much of that arsenal is actually *deployable*. If a single bomb is used to put pressure on negotiations, how would the other party react ? Would there be a full retaliation..

Comment: @Goodies I think that this question is answerable at some approximate order of magnitude level. I'm not looking for an answer with three significant digit precision, just a rough ballpark. If particular conditions like where it was done or under what conditions mattered, I'd want to know what those factors would be.

Comment: WW2 was a very large war. It is the only war in which atomic bombs were used. And it did not render any area unimhabitable for a decade. On the other hand, WW1 was also a very large war; although no atomic bombs were used, areas much larger than a city were rendered [uninhabitable for quite a long time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_Rouge).

Comment: *"This question is answerable at some approximate order of magnitude":* and order of magnitude of what? What is the metric? I have no idea how to measure the bigness of a war.

Comment: @AlexP Number of strikes? Megatons of explosives used? Something like that. I'd be open to other sensible or easier to work with definitions.

Comment: @ohwilleke see my comment text.. there are hundreds  of factors involved. A question "how big" is posing issues anyway. You could try to compute a certain amount of nuclear arms, and say the atmosphere would reach a critical point, were nuclear winter is unavoidable. But you can't determine that without all parameters. A count only won't do. If I drop 30 hydrogen bombs om Antarctica, there would be no nuclear winter, because there will be no dust in the atmosphere. If I drop 30 hydrogen bombs on Siberian military bases, the effect would be larger.. but how much larger, nobody knows.

Comment: But the question does not ask how many strikes, not does it ask how many megatons. It asks how big a war. Strikes and megatons are easy: the Americans, the British, the French and the Russians detonated many atomic bombs during the 1950s and 1960s, so you can easily count them and add up the amount of energy released to get a baseline number of strikes and megatons which very obviously did not cause a nuclear winter. (You will be surprised how many bombs and total megatons those four civilized nations detonated. You can definitely have a reasonably large war.)

Comment: This was a fairly easy question to answer, since lots of people online have asked how big a nuclear has to be to cause a nuclear winter.

Comment: @AlexP it could be *any* number.. you *cannot* calculate this just from counts and megatons, nor do you know how "big" your war would need to be, because political circumstances are not specified. This kind of models need to be dynamic. There is a delta, for each aspect. All delta's together predict the first second. Then you evaluate new circumstances, simulate the next second by running your model again. To do that world wide exceeds capacity of computers, even advanced weather models. Suppose London will be bombed, you need a 5 days wheather predictions to say what will happen in Amsterdam.

Comment: Strikes on military targets, or strikes on cities? Tactical nukes fired against missile launching sites, will not lead to an apocalypse.

Comment: Your assumptions are entirely based on unsubstantiated  conjecture. Consider it would take over 100 of the most modern nukes to completely destroy just the main area of the City of New York, and the effects would not even reach Pennsylvania, the answer is 'a conflagration at least 50 times greater than the combined might of every nuclear power currently on Earth today'. There would be no 'nuclear winter' with just today's number of nukes.

Comment: It depends on modus operandi, nuking area with high population density yields instant result of more death but hitting nuclear power plants will spread deadly radioactive particulates far and wide. The question now is how many Chernobyl disasters does it takes to throw back into stone age?

Comment: Very large. Nuclear weapons are not as dirty as we're led to believe. We could survive losing over 90% of the population as a species... but our living standards would regress to something comparable to the medieval (the last time the earth only had a billion or so people). Modern civilisation depends on the number of people we have... mining, selling insurance... plumbing baths... but the survival of our species does not require A4 lined paper, or hedge fund managers. We could probably bomb ourselves back to the stone age without humanity becoming extinct.

Comment: The truth is that no one knows with certainty how many could cause apocalypse in the literal sense. It was deemed a moral apocalypse early on by some of the same scientists that developed the weapon, many wanted to see it never used again. So any claims of a literal apocalypse might well be propaganda designed to achieve that goal. The uncertainty of a never-observed-event allows enough wiggle room to make the propaganda plausible.

Comment: @AlexP The problem with your comparison is that weapons tests were done in areas with nothing much of value in them.  They didn't make a lot of smoke.  Furthermore, the smoke is only a big problem if it goes high enough--the dire predictions from the oil fires of Desert Storm didn't come about because the smoke quickly rained out.  Nuclear winter requires smoke above the rain and that takes reasonably large h-bombs (to go high enough) on cities (to make enough smoke.)  The world has zero such events to measure.

Answer (score 1):

Between 1945 and 1963 there were more than 400[*] nuclear explosions in the atmosphere. Since they were spread over a period of 15/18 years there was time for some dust to settle, their effect was not fully cumulative. Except for 1962, US and Russia wanted to test as much as they could before the [ban of atmospheric testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_Test_Ban_Treaty) went into effect and they conducted more than 100 tests in a single year, furthermore the big number of tests of 1962 was preceded by the big and inefficient tsar bomba in 1961.

So, since we are still alive and experienced no nuclear winter you can assume that more than 100 explosions are still within the safe threshold. Then it depends on what type of bombs could be used. Modern thermonuclear bombs would have a devastating effect, but would produce less waste, the bombs with the smallest amount of toxic by-product would be one based on the fusion of tritium, but since tritium is difficult to produce and has a short half life the number of available bombs would be limited. Anyway a lot will depend on the type and technology of the weapons, but with modern technology you can expect a conservative threshold over 200 bombs if the war happens in a very short period of time like could be an exchange of ICBM between two powers. If the war is fought over a prolonged period the threshold might be higher.

[*] http://fingfx.thomsonreuters.com/gfx/rngs/NORTHKOREA-MISSILES/010050Y324P/index.html
e
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapons_testing

Answer (score 0):

## It depends on what they hit, but 100 good strikes.

Hiroshoma was especially bad not just because there was a big boom, but because the city burned down. The burning down of hiroshima released 1000 times more energy than the actual nuke.

Assuming they all hit cities, and cause a similar amount of burning, [100 cities burnt to ashes should be enough.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_winter)

It's also dependent on rain. If there's heavy raining around the time of the nuking, that might reduce the amount of ash sent up.

Comment: So, for example, ten strikes might not lead to nuclear winter, at least if the conditions in the places where the strikes occurred were right.

Comment: Yeah. If there was heavy rain, or if it was on a military location where there was little material to burn, it might not produce much global warming.

Comment: @NepeneNep Exactly. It depends on weather and location and some other things, like building density. That is why you would have to consider 1000 scenarios with 100's of different parameters to answer this.. and you won't be able to calculate it, like Wiki seems to do. Putting "100 strikes" as answer is completely *arbitrary*. Wiki sais *"the ignition of 100 firestorms, each comparable in intensity to that observed in Hiroshima in 1945, could produce a "small" nuclear winter"*  but  without any precise data about where the nukes landed and how much dust was released. Issue: you *don't know*.

Comment: It requires certain amount of combustibles per square meter to get a firestorm going as determined via study/investigation of bombing of German cities. Most modern cities do not have that amount of combustibles. So huge fires won't be a thing for most cities. Limited fires yes, massive city consuming firestorms, no.

Comment: 50,000 nukes would not cause a Nuclear Winter. The surface area of the world is just too big. 50,000 nukes would be like a bug hitting a car windshield. Just look at the miniscule damage hundreds of cruise missiles did in Syria. Compared to a nuke, the Earth is HUGE

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond we are also bugs in scope of the earth.  But there are actions we can take to shift the environment.  Of course the earth will keep going.  An ice age or two hasn't stopped it yet.

Comment: @Cort Ammon
 Look at all of the recent natural disasters and fires. We escape pretty much unscathed, and keep  going as a society.  Nuclear war would be no different. There will be no nuclear apocalypse with our current level of nuclear weapons. That is a pure sci-fi trope.

Comment: The Australia wildfires only released twice the energy of the fires caused by hiroshima, over a much longer period of time. We haven't had big enough fires to cause a nuclear winter.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond You might be interested in the Wikipedia article on [nuclear winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_winter).  There are indeed strong opinions that there will not be a nuclear winter, but they rely on modeling rather than metaphor.  "Nuclear autumn" is apparently decently popular these days.  But most agree that we do have a noticeable effect.  it's not a bug in a windshield thing.  Its a particularly large bug making a very large mess over your windshield.

Comment: A quote I found useful for setting the scale, both how big and how small these effects are: "This amount of black carbon far exceeds that which has been emitted in the atmosphere by all volcanic eruptions in the past 1,200 years but is less than the asteroid impact which caused a mass extinction event 66 million years ago"

Comment: @Cort Ammon
 You might be interested in the articles that thoroughly discuss the mass panic after the War of the Worlds broadcast in America. Factually, however, there WAS no panic. It was 'ho-hum'. The 'panic' myth was propagated by newspaper publishers, that were trying to discredit radio. There is not a single credible reference in ANY  news media just after the broadcast that even suggested there was mild disruption, let alone panic.

Comment: The burning down of a city does not push the ashes that high in the atmosphere. They won't persist for a long time unless there are exceptional conditions like the thermal currents of a desert.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to cause nearly as much destruction in order to devastate the modern world through the use of nuclear weapons. Nuclear winter is caused by the fine particulate dust which is kicked up from the explosion. That increased dust in the upper atmosphere blocks incoming sunlight. The destruction of cities is not really needed to cause havoc. It makes for a scary image on TV, but is less effective than exploding nuclear weapons to create high-altitude electromagnetic pulses. “A nuclear detonation in the upper atmosphere creates an electromagnetic pulse (EMP), a powerful, damaging electromagnetic field covering a subcontinent-scale region.” (https://eiscouncil.org/emp-high-altitude-electromagnetic-pulse/)

“The detonation of a nuclear weapon at an altitude of approximately 500 kilometers over
the United States will generate a near-continental scale high altitude electromagnetic pulse
(HEMP). The effects of such an attack may instantaneously destroy or disrupt substantial
portions of the electrical and electronic systems that operate the critical infrastructure of the United States, as well as portions of Canada and Mexico.” (https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA424218.pdf) The fact that a single high-altitude nuclear explosion could destroy the electrical infrastructure across a majority of the U.S. vastly exceeds the damage which would be cause attacking a single city.

Other benefits(?) of a high-altitude nuclear explosion include a lack of nuclear winter, as no dust is propelled into the atmosphere, and the radioactive fallout being scattered by the jet stream, causing a slight increase over a wide geographical area while preventing a single “hot” area. No fires from the strikes, and no pressure waves.

The initial negative impact of such an event would be the destruction or damage of the technological infrastructure modern nations depend upon. Modern vehicles require computers to operate. Fry those computers and vehicles will not work. Cell phones would no longer work, cutting people off from their sole source of information. No internet, electricity, radio equipment, banking, or other niceties people rely upon. The destruction of airplanes as their electronics are fried, leaving them to resort to dead-stick landings, many of which would not be successful. People at work could become stranded far from their homes and families. The blinding of anyone looking at the explosion when it occurs.

Secondary negative impacts include a lack of water as water towers run dry without electricity to refill them, food spoilage due to a lack of refrigeration, heat/cold related injuries and deaths, deaths from a lack of life-saving medications, and the eventual failure of certain nuclear powerplants unable to utilize shutdown measures. While the initial uncertainty would prevent a massive negative public reaction, as time went on this would eventually happen. The looting of stores for supplies would add to the unrest. As most people fail to stock enough food to last more than a few days, starvation would quickly become an issue. Chemical spills and other leaking toxic material could cause localized areas of death.

“Nine of 10 Americans are dead from starvation, disease, and societal collapse. The United States of America ceases to exist,” warned the report declassified by recently decommissioned U.S. Commission to Assess the Threat to the United States from Electromagnetic Pulse (EMP) Attack.” (https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/washington-secrets/new-emp-warning-us-will-cease-to-exist-90-of-population-will-die) So there you go, you can have your nuclear war which results in the death of 90% of the world’s population without the additional negative effects of nuclear winter and a radioactive wasteland. You could have several nukes hit major cities as well, to increase the physical destruction and leave some uninhabitable zones. You would end up getting some immediate global cooling, but that would fade over the years.

As for your question, how big could a nuclear war be without causing an apocalypse, a study from 2018 stated that using more than 100 nukes against an adversary would cause harm to the aggressor nation. (https://www.mdpi.com/2313-576X/4/2/25) I am sure some of this depends upon the yield of the weapons, but it is a good starting point. This number does not take into account high-altitude EMP bursts. A report by Rutgers University (https://climate.envsci.rutgers.edu/pdf/WiresClimateChangeNW.pdf) states that a full-scale nuclear war between Russia and the U.S. would result in a nuclear winter which could last for years. This would involve the launch of ten thousand nukes, so a bit more than the hundred or so quoted above.

It might help to explain the purpose for asking the question. It seems unlikely that people would get into a nuclear exchange and stop when they reached the point of no return. If they have resorted to nukes, things are bad.